# return curl response as object instead of string

Tags: php, curl

I'm making curl request. It returns string instead of json.

case 1)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->accessTokenUri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->accessTokenhttpQuery);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

\Log::info($result);
\Log::info(gettype($result));
```

this prints

> invalid_request

case 2) without httpheaders

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->accessTokenUri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->accessTokenhttpQuery);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

\Log::info($result);
\Log::info(gettype($result));
```

this prints

> result and gettype is string.

I tried

a) `json_encode($result)` which says object of std class couldn't be converted to string.

b) `json_decode(json_encode($result, true));` - still not working

Final one

```
$tokenGrantParams =  array(
    "grant_type" => "test1",
    "client_id" => "test2",
    "client_secret" => "test3"
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"urlhere");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($tokenGrantParams));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$d = json_decode($result);
return $d;
```

what do I do to get request as object ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($result);` show?

Comment: Are you sure that the response is a [valid JSON string](https://jsonlint.com/) that can be decoded by `json_decode`?

Comment: var_dump result - string(723) "{"access_token":"jwt_token","expires_in":86400,"token_type":"Bearer"}"

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili That string can be decoded just fine by `json_decode`. What do you mean by **"still not working"**? Does it throw an exception does it return a value you're not expecting? (btw, `json_decode` with the second parameter set to `true` will return an associative array not an object)

Comment: When I try json_decode, error is thrown stating : The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given. {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), \"object\" given. at C:\\Users\\glagh\\Desktop\\Work\\Translive_API\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Response.php:401)"} []

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact code you're using to decode the response (including the curl setup and execution part).

Comment: I updated the code. look at the third code .

Comment: Are you returning that value `return $d;` from a Laravel controller action method?

Comment: `json_decode()` would not throw the error that you're showing.  `var_dump($d);` and you'll probably see that it is an object.  Wherever you are `return`ing to seems to be expecting something different.

Comment: $result = json_decode($result); var_dump($result) - > prints NULL

Comment: @Bogdan I wrote that curl request in Route::get("/r", function(){ here });

Comment: those last lines seem redundant, why not `return json_decode($result)`? Also if it's printing null then $result .. well is null. Hence json_decode won't work.

Comment: "json_encode($result) which says object of std class couldn't be converted to string."

Normally, its because the result class isn´t include yet. 

json_decode($result);  -> MyClass without include ('myclass.php')